# get html tag in order in vba

Tags: html, excel, vba, web-scraping, element

I am scrapping through a website to print out data to excel sheet

```
<div class="article-content">
  <h4> ３１. 出勤 – しゅっきん : đi làm</h4>
  <h5> Ví dụ :</h5>
  <p> 毎朝８時に出勤している:
     <br> Hàng sáng tôi đi làm vào lúc 8h
     <br> 多くの会社では出勤時間は９時だ
     <br> Nhiều công ty đều quy định giờ làm việc là 9h</p>

  <h4> ３２. 出世 – しゅっせ : thăng tiến</h4>
  <h5> Ví dụ :</h5>
  <p>出世もしたいが、仕事ばかりの人生の嫌だ.
     <br> Tớ muốn thăng tiến nhưng mà lại gét cuộc sống toàn công việc
     <br> 同期の中で、山田さんが一番出世が早い。
     <br> Trong số những người cùng khóa, anh yamada là người thăng tiến nhanh nhất</p>
</div>
```

I want to extract to a text like this

```
３１. 出勤 – しゅっきん : đi làm
毎朝８時に出勤している:
<br> Hàng sáng tôi đi làm vào lúc 8h
<br> 多くの会社では出勤時間は９時だ
<br> Nhiều công ty đều quy định giờ làm việc là 9h

３２. 出世 – しゅっせ : thăng tiến
出世もしたいが、仕事ばかりの人生の嫌だ.
<br> Tớ muốn thăng tiến nhưng mà lại gét cuộc sống toàn công việc
<br> 同期の中で、山田さんが一番出世が早い。
<br> Trong số những người cùng khóa, anh yamada là người thăng tiến nhanh nhất
```

My Code in this moment: I already extracted all p tag content, but I need h4 tag to sort it out

```
Dim IE As Object
Set IE = CreateObject("internetexplorer.application")

IE.Visible = True
IE.navigate "https://tuhoconline.net/tu-vung-n2-sach-mimi-kara-oboeru-4.html"

Do While IE.readyState <> 4
DoEvents
Loop

Set doc = IE.document

For i = 0 To 50
    inputText = doc.getElementsByTagName("p")(i).innerHTML
    outputStr() = Split(inputText, "<br>")
```

I tried `getElementsByClassName` or `getElementsByTagName` but it was separated and cannot combined in the order I wanted, anyone have a solution to this in VBA?
Really appriceated

Comment: Can we knoe the URL of the website ?

Comment: This site: https://tuhoconline.net/tu-vung-n2-sach-mimi-kara-oboeru-4.html

Comment: Also, include your code so far.

Comment: thank you, I edited my question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### **CSS selectors:**

You can use CSS selectors to target the info you want.

**Pattern 1:**

```
.article-content h4
```

This is `h4` tags within elements with class `article-content`. There are 10 on the page.  The [`"."`](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_class.asp) is the class selector.

**Pattern 2:**

```
.article-content h4 + h5 + p
```

You want the first paragraph, after an `h5` tag, which is after an `h4` tag, within elements with class `article-content`. There are 10 of these, so all good.

The [`"+"`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Adjacent_sibling_selectors) is the adjacent sibling combinator. It separates two selectors and matches the second element only if it immediately follows the first element, and both are children of the same parent element.

---

### Notes:

As more than one item is matched in each case i.e. for both patterns, you use the `querySelectorAll` method of `document`, to return a `nodeList` of matched elements. You then traverse the `.Length` of this list,  indexing into the `nodeList` to retrieve items.

I do away with the opening of a browser and issue an [XmlHttpRequest](https://codingislove.com/http-requests-excel-vba/) `GET` request. This is a much faster method of retrieving your page content.

---

## CSS queries in action (applying the CSS selectors)

**Pattern 1: sample of matched results**

[image: Sample]

**Pattern 2: sample of matched results**

[image: Sample 2]

---

### **VBA:**

As follows:

```
Option Explicit
Public Sub GetInfo()
    Dim sResponse As String, html As New HTMLDocument, i As Long, hNodeList As Object, pNodeList As Object

    With CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
        .Open "GET", "https://tuhoconline.net/tu-vung-n2-sach-mimi-kara-oboeru-4.html", False
        .send
        sResponse = StrConv(.responseBody, vbUnicode)
    End With

    sResponse = Mid$(sResponse, InStr(1, sResponse, "<!DOCTYPE "))

    With html
       .body.innerHTML = sResponse
      Set hNodeList = .querySelectorAll(".article-content h4")
      Set pNodeList = .querySelectorAll(".article-content h4 + h5 + p")

      For i = 0 To hNodeList.Length - 1
          Debug.Print hNodeList.item(i).innerText
          Debug.Print pNodeList.item(i).innerText
      Next i
    End With
End Sub
```

---

**References: via VBA > Tools > References**

HTML Object Library